# Optimal way to construct an instance from an http request parameters

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, constructor, http-request-parameters

In my project i have:

1. a servlet that handles http requests with users profile info as parameters, i.e (userName = "Bob" , password = "ugaBaga", address = "blabla"... )
2. a User class that represents the user info. getters + setters : getName(), setName(String username)....

my question is , is there an easy way to create a new user instance from the httpRequest parameters?

something like :

User newUser = createUserFromParams (new User(), httpRequestParameters);

(without the need to write : user.setName(parameters.getParameter("userName")) for each of my 30~ fields)

p.s - I'm not really sending a password, i couldn't think of a fieldname.
the passwords are being sent by sms's ;)

thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, there is. And that is when you define the helper function with signature `User createUserFromParams (User user, Map<String, String> parameters)`, for example!

Comment: A side note...never, ever send passwords in an http request...

Comment: @ZackMacomber How then it would reach the server? Probably what you meant is 'never send passwords via a GET request'?

Comment: as in it should be sent via SSL (https)...I should have said unencrypted http request

Answer (score 0):

There is the HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap, but that delivers a `Map<String, String[]>` as you could have `?a=1&a=2'. So something like a BeanUtils will not do.

But you can make your own utility class using java reflection, or translate the request parameters to `Map<String, String>` and use a standard bean utility ([apache](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/api/)).

Answer (score 0):

There are several MVC Frameworks in Java Ecosystem that handles that particular issue -binding request parameters to a particular class- being my favorite one Spring MVC. One of the benefits of the Framework according [Spring Site](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch20s09.html) is:

> Command/form objects to bind parameters to: as bean properties or
>   fields, with customizable type conversion, depending on @InitBinder
>   methods and/or the HandlerAdapter configuration

So using Spring Framework there's no need for Hand-made binding: Spring does that for you. So if are not a believer in [NIH philosofy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) you should try an MVC Framework, being Spring or not.

**PS:** If you still won't o can't use an MVC Framework, you can made use of `HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap()` and good-old Apache Commons `BeanUtils.populate()` (more info in the [method's JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtilsBean.html#populate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map%29)) to made the binding for you.